What is the minimum value of k before this puzzle becomes impossible?
Construct an infinite by infinite grid of nodes. Draw edges from each of the nodes to each node less than $3$ (NOT less than or equal to 3) unit distances away from it. This means that $\left(0,0\right)$ is connected to
\begin{align}
& (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, -1), (2, -2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1),
\\ & (1, -2), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, -1), (0, -2), (-1, 2), (-1, 1), (-1, 0),
\\ &  (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, 2), (-2, 1),
(-2, 0), (-2, -1)\ \mbox{and}\ (-2, -2)
\end{align}
This also means that each node is connected to exactly $24$ other nodes.
In this puzzle, you're a police chief trying to catch a bank robber on the run. Think of each of the edges as freeways and each of the nodes as interchanges. You're allowed to place up to k blockades each hour, and the robber arrives at a new interchange each hour. These blockades stop traffic in just $1$ direction, not both. However, you may blockade traffic from going in either direction using $2$ blockades, which could either be placed in the same hour or different hours. The chief knows where the robber is all times. The robber is caught if it ever gets trapped at a node with no edges. The robber is aware of all blockades you place. The robber also doesn't have to change his position each hour if he doesn't want to (even though it's a bad idea to stay where you are, and I'll explain that in a minute). What is the minimum value of k before it becomes impossible to catch the robber in a finite amount of time, assuming the robber plays the optimal strategy, whatever that may be?
I haven't made too much progress on this problem. The lowest value I've proven that is possible for this problem is $k = 23$, or in other words, $23$ blockades per hour. With $k = 23$, if from the starting position, you prevent the robber from going to any node except the one directly above him, he will be forced to that node. Then you can block every path except for the one that goes directly back to the starting position. He will be forced back to the starting position, and then you just have $1$ road block to place before he is trapped there.
I'd also be interested in lower and upper bounds to this problem. Please post any and all progress you make on this problem in the comments (or answers) here.
Note that though this is similar to the angel problem, it is NOT the same as the angel problem. If you have never heard of the angel problem, it goes like this. You start with an infinite by infinite grid of squares and the angel starts at the origin. The angel may move up to $k$ spaces away, diagonally, vertically, horizontally, or some combination of the three. After doing so, the Devil removes $1$ tile, meaning that the angel can no longer go to that tile. If the angel has nowhere it can run to, the angel is defeated and the Devil wins. Code Parade has a video on it: The Angel Problem. Anyways, in the angel problem, we were removing tiles, which would be analogous to nodes in this puzzle. In this puzzle, we are removing edges. Another way in which this problem is different is that in the angel problem, the parameter we were tweaking was the distance the angel could travel while the amount of tiles the devil could move stays fixed in place. Here the parameter we are tweaking is the amount of edges the chief can move while the distance the robber can move stays fixed in place.
Also take note that much like the angel problem, it would never benefit the robber to go to a node it could have gone to in the past. It strictly benefits the chief. This is because the chief would get $k$ extra road blocks to place, while the robber remains in the same place.
Here is some more information that could potentially be helpful for solving the problem: After zero hours, there is just $1$ spot the robber could be at. After the first hour, there are $25$ different nodes that the robber could be at. After the second hour, there are $49$ different nodes the robber could be at. After the third hour, there are $81$ nodes the robber could be at. After the fourth, there are $121$ nodes the robber could be at. In general, at hour n, there are $\left(2n + 1\right)^{2}$ or, if you expand that out, $4n^{2} + 4n + 1$ nodes the robber could be at. Another potentially helpful fact is that if you don't do anything to stop the robber, after $n$ hours there will be $25^{n}$ different paths the robber could have taken, though after enough time has passed the vast majority of these paths will be highly inefficient for escape.
Here are some other questions you might ask which could be useful to the original problem (to be clear these are not meant to be questions of their own. They are meant to be possible stepping stones to the answer to the main question we're asking):

If you have an $m$ by $n$ chunk of nodes, how many edges are completely contained in this chunk? What about if you include all edges connected to these nodes?
Given node $\left(x, y\right)$, how many ways will there be for the robber to get to that node after $n$ hours?
What is the optimal strategy for the robber?
What is the optimal strategy for the chief?

As the chief, you could try a similar strategy you would try in the angel problem. It's a bit complicated to explain with words alone, so if you haven't already I'd recommend watching that code parade video or, if you already have seen it, skip to the time stamp $1$:$48$ and think about how you'd apply that strategy to this problem. Using this strategy my half-ways-between-a-theorem-and-a-conjecture is that it will still be possible to catch the robber at $k = 21$.
I found it surprisingly difficult to prove that it is impossible with $k = 1$.

1/ Can you state your solution for $k = 23$?  $\quad$ 2/ Is the distance of $< 3$ a taxicab distance or Euclidean distance? In particular,  is $(0, 0)$ connected to $(1, 1) $ and $(1, 2)$? $\quad$ 3/ To check, do we know where the bank robber starts off from?

The bank robber starts from (0, 0), and is able to go to (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, -1), (2, -2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, -2), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, -1), (0, -2), (-1, 2), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, 2), (-2, 1), (-2, 0), (-2, -1), and (-2, -2). I'll edit my question after I leave this comment to state this. I edited my comment a short while ago stating my solution for k = 23, which I'm guessing was written after you clicked on my comment which is why you didn't see it.

Thirteen versions in six hours. It's hard to hit a moving target

I'm just now realizing how many articulatory mistakes I have made in the body of this question. If you see something that could possibly be another mistake, please let me know so that I can fix it.

Better to fix the mistakes before you post, Nico. Now on version 17. Each edit pushes the question back to the top of the front page, pushing newer questions down.

I know. Grammar was never really my thing and unlike many places, it doesn't point out grammar mistakes.

With $k=16$, the police has a winning strategy.
We can limit the robber to nodes $A=\{(0,0)(0,1)(0,-1)(1,0)(-1,0)(1,1)(1,-1)(-1,1)(-1,-1) \}$ = the $9$ nodes at a distance less than $\sqrt{2}$ from $(0,0)$.
We can check that the diameter of this set of nodes is less than 3. So when the robber is in one node from this list, all 8 other nodes are in the list of 24 nodes he can visit.
As long as the robber is in this area, the list of 24 neighbors contains 8 nodes from this list (the 9th node is the node where the robber stands).
So the list of 24 nodes that the robber can reach contains exactly 16 nodes that are not in our set $A$, and with $k=16$, we can close those $16$ edges.
So, we can always limit the robber to this area. And at one moment, the robber will have to go back to a node already visited. And the next step will be the last one.
** VERY IMPORTANT EDIT :**
This solution with k=16 is 'immediate'. We can improve it. Let try with k=15.
I consider the 'center of the city', I choose a point $C(0.453, 0.301)$. I choose numbers with many digits, to avoid problems like symmetry.
At each step, the policeman looks at all 24 points that the robber can reach, and he will select the $k=15$ points with the distance to $C$ maximum. The policeman will close the edges to those 15 points.
With this strategy, the number of nodes that the robber can visit is fix, the police will catch the robber.

With k= 12, with the same strategy, it also works.
This picture illustrates the solution : Police accepts that the robber travel in those 134 points. For each point in this schema, when we look at the 24 'neighbors', at least 12 of them are in the set of 134 points. So the police can close all edges that go out of our set of 134 points.
With k=11, it seems that the police has a winning strategy.
In previous picture, we have 22 red points, 22 critical points. For those 22 points, we have 12 neighbors which are out of the 'authorized area'. For all other points, we have maximum 11 points that are outside of the 'authorized area'.
So, at round n°1, the police can select 11 of those critical points, and put one barrier on the 'frontier' for each of those points.
Same strategy at round n°2, with the 11 other critical points.
And now, we are ok.
The robber cannot escape from the authorized area.
This is a winning strategy for the police with k=11.

This is an impressive result, and the most satisfying answer I've seen to any of my questions yet, but this still isn't a proof that there is not another, even better strategy for the chief.
